# C# - Add Item to Listbox on Form from a Class

Tags: c#, class, websocket, listbox, server

I'm trying to do a simple WebSocket Server in C# that will communicate with a Client in JavaScript, the code I am testing is this:

**Websocket-sharp Server**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WebSocketSharp;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;

namespace MyProgram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var wssv = new WebSocketServer(8081);

            wssv.WaitTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

            wssv.AddWebSocketService<NFP>("/");

            wssv.Start();
        }
    }

    public class NFP : WebSocketBehavior
    {
        protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

            Send("Received");
        }

        protected override void OnError(ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.Exception);
        }

        protected override void OnClose(CloseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.Code);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I was wondering, how do I send the message received at OnMessage for the ListBox that is on Form1 already open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define the target listbox as a property for your NPF class:

   `public ListBox Target {get; set;}`
2. set the target in your button1_Click method:

   `wssv.Target = myListBox;`
3. When you receive the message add it to the listbox. However, since you are in a different Thread to the UI Thread (which is the only one that may modify controls on the Form), you have to call the `Invoke` member on the `Target` to do your work:

   ```
   protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

       if (Target != null)
           Target.Invoke( () => {Target.Items.Add(e.Message);});

       Send("Received");
   }
   ```

Comment: The Target will not work because the "wssv" is a new WebSocketServer and not an instance of the NFP class.

Comment: @Anderson Costa - Ok, I got that part wrong - I am not familiar withe the WebSocketeServer class, but you must somehow be able to drill down to the NFP object (maybe from the return value of `AddWebSocketService` ?  ) and then set the Target property there.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to use [Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838207(v=vs.95).aspx)  in c#.

But if you want a fast solution you can create this class:

```
public static class ListBoxAdder
{
    public static void Add(ListBox listbox, string newItem)
    {
        listbox.Items.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

in Form1 declare

```
public static ListBox listBox;
```

and finally

```
protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
{
  ListBoxAdder.Add(Form1.listBox, e.Data);
}
```